# PHP: move_uploaded_file Issues. What's wrong here?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having a very difficult getting this working and I have yet to come up with a working scenario.  Basically, this is a simple user-friendly admin which is supposed to upload an image.  However, I can't get the upload to work.  The filename is getting added to the database just fine but the image will not upload.

Here's the code as is:

```
function editMain($data){
  array_pop($data);
  $where = "main_id = {$data['main_id']}";
  unset($data['main_id']);
//upload image
if ($_FILES['main_picture']['size'] > 1){ //if image deal with it
  $data['main_picture'] = '/images/'.$_FILES['main_picture']['name'];
  $uploadedfile = $_FILES['main_picture']['tmp_name'];
  if (move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile, SITE_ROOT.$data['main_picture']))
  echo "successfully uploaded {$data['main_picture']}<br />";
  else 
  echo "failed to upload {$data['main_picture']}<br />";
}
```

Thanks for looking and thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: What does `SITE_ROOT` signify?

Comment: check the paths and permissions on those folders (try 777 to see if that helps - but change that later for security) - ie check `is_writable( SITE_ROOT.$data['main_picture'] )`

Comment: SITE_ROOT is set to be the domain (ie: http : // www . example . com /).

Comment: I have also been playing with the permissions and unless they're not saving, that does not seem to affect it when it's set to 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SITE_ROOT` needs to be a local directory, ie "`C:\...`" or "`/home/...`", it cannot be a URL structure. Change that to the local directory of where the file should be uploaded, check permissions, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use it that way:

```
   if(!is_dir($dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/fies_path"))mkdir($dir);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$src = $dir."/$file_name.ext");
```